Mailchimp Survey Response API call only returning 25 responses when more exists
I'm experiencing an issue that we believe is a bug with this endpoint:
/reporting/surveys/{outreach_id}/responses
(https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/reporting-surveys/)
When I do this call, only a maximum of 25 responses are returned even when the outreach_id in question has more responses. I have tried using pagination to force more responses to be returned, but it still just returns 25.
Here is an example shown in Postman:

You can see for the outreach_id 07fca9fc8327 the total number of responses is 595 (as seen in the total_responses key in the API response body).
But when I do the survey response call for the same outreach_id we only get back 25 responses returned, even though there are a total of 595. This can be seen in the screenshot below, the number of items and the total_items in the response body is both 25. And in this example I am using pagination to try and force a max of 1000 records to be returned but that still doesn't work.

Was wondering if anyone else is experiencing this too or if there's anything that I'm doing wrong with the API call?
If this is an API bug and others are experiencing it, does anyone have any work arounds? I have emailed mailchimp's apihelp account a few weeks ago but have not heard back

Have you tried an offset in your paginated request?

yep I tried that, it looks like for this route the offset query parameter doesn't work (or is broken as well). Whether I set the offset to 25 or 1000, it alwarys returns the same 25 records everytime
